# which is the best way to declare Serial while creating Arduino library?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, library, softwareserial, serial-data

Well, I am trying make a library for HMI display. display and Arduino comminicate with Serial. So I will so many times Serial port. Generally I will use **Serial.write** commend. if I examine other libraries, there are lots way to declare serial. Why and which is the best I want to learn.

there I have seen declaring Serial methods.

**Method 1**

in library .h file

```
nothing
```

in library .cpp file

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial SIM(RX_PIN,TX_PIN);

void KapadokyaGSM::basla(){
    SIM.begin(9600);
  _tampon.reserve(255);
}
```

**Method 2**

in library .h file

```
public:
EasyNex(HardwareSerial& serial);
...
private:
HardwareSerial* _serial;
...
```

in library .cpp file

```
EasyNex::EasyNex(HardwareSerial& serial){  // Constructor's parameter is the Serial we want to use
_serial = &serial;
}

void EasyNex::begin(unsigned long baud){
_serial->begin(baud);  // We pass the initialization data to the objects (baud rate) default: 9600
delay(100);            // Wait for the Serial to initialize
```

Also I have seen declaring with Stream but now i didnt find example codes. So finally **Can anyone tell me what is the best for declearing Serial in library.** it can be for only hardware serial or both

Comment: The basic concept that you're asking about is called _dependency injection_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As regards the use of `Stream`:

I usually use `Stream` instead of `HardwareSerial` because:

- It allows the use of other serial devices, like `SoftwareSerial` or `USBSerial` that aren't "Hardware" UARTs.
- It even allows the use of non-serial systems, like sending data over networks or wireless devices

However it means:

- The user has to manually initialize their serial object / device as `Stream` has no facility for setting things like baud rates.

Comment: Can you show me a tutorial, or github library which is using Stream.

Comment: @mehmet try this one: https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/ICSC/tree/master/src

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way, the first is using a global variable, being static. The second is dynamically (or at least to pass a serial instance).

It depends on your use

- If you want your code always to work with the same declared serial (hardware or serial) instance, you can use the first method, as it is the easiest.
- If you want your serial hardware port to be flexible (your code to work e.g. with a selectable hardware serial port on an Arduino Mega), you need the second.
- If you want to your serial port to be either software or hardware, you can use the second method, but you need another type (not the mentioned `HardwareSerial` class. I don't know by head the parent class of `SoftwareSerial` and `HardwareSerial` (The `Stream` class you mentioned could be a common parent class).

Comment: there is no Serial base class

Comment: Can i ask a last question, why second method uses "->" and Why not "." Such us _serial.begin(baud). Is this totally same

Comment: If you have access to the object itself, e.g., `Serial`, you can say `Serial.println()`. If your library only has a pointer to the object, you have use `->`, the dereference operator: `serialPtr->println()`. The result is the same: calling the object's 'println()' member. The difference is in how the compiled code gets you to that member.

Comment: @Juraj Thanks for that addition (I was not sure, so I removed the comment about not being sure and the statement in my answer).

Comment: @mehmet, it is common C++ object member access you asked about